# Why the overlapping tags for setting table style settings that (apparently) would do the same thing?

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

n.b. This concerns HTML-email coding (limitations apply)

For example in the Mail Chimp email template I'm working with there is this:

```
<td valign="middle" width="140" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: left;">
```

I guess they're covering bases but when should one use `valign="top"` and when do I use `style="vertical-align: top;"` (and when use both)?

What's the history that leads to this confusing state of style assignment?

Answer (score 2):

`valign` is deprecated and should not be used in newer applications, as its support is not guaranteed to be there in future versions of current browsers. `vertical-align` is the recommended CSS way of vertically aligning content.

See this link for details: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: Thanks for link. So it's correct to use both ways when sending to an assortment of unknown Mail Clients?

Comment: Yes. The only thing to ensure is you use both and not `valign` alone as that could be unsupported in the target client software. Also using `display:table-cell;` along with `vertical-align` will enable you to have this on non-TD elements as well.

Comment: 'non-TD elements' such as… TR elements or something else all together?

Answer (score 1):

Since `valign` is deprecated, some email clients might not render it. So, there's the inline CSS fallback (since HTML emails require inline CSS).

I think the main reason why it is used in this case is so that no matter what, the `<td>` is being vertically aligned in the middle.